# Accessing nodes in Shadow root

Tags: dart, dart-html, shadow-dom

I've my custom element defined as:

```
class purchaseLines extends HtmlElement {
  static final tag = 'purchase-lines';
  factory purchaseLines() => new Element.tag(tag);

  var shadow, innerDiv;

  purchaseLines.created() : super.created() {
     var shadow = this.createShadowRoot();      
     innerDiv = new cardFonix()..width='310px'..height ='80px';

   var LineNumber = new InputFonix('serial#')..iw=20;
   var LineItem = new InputFonix('item code');
   var LineQty = new InputFonix('Qty')..type='number';
   var lRDD = new InputFonix('R. Delivery')..type='date';

   innerDiv.container.nodes..add(LineItem)..add(LineQty)..add(lRDD); 

   shadow.nodes.add(innerDiv);
   }
 }
```

and it is displaying the required correctly, as in the attached.

I'm trying to read how many lines cards had been entered, and th value of each item in each card.

1. For reading number of lines cards, I used the below statement, and its functioned correctly.

   print(this.parent.nodes.length);
2. My problem with reading the elements values in each card / custom element, and I can not go deeper with nodes.nodes... and got this error

   - There is no such getter 'length' in 'Node'

how can I read the values of each item in the shadow? I found in DART a shadowRoot, but not sure if it is related to my issue or some thing else, I googled as I can, and found no answer :(

```
![developer tool output][1]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The secret was in the ***shadowRoot***

I was able to access it using the following code:

```
this.parent.nodes[0].shadowRoot.nodes
```